# Ktor Client, install (Auth)

Tags: авторизация, httpclient, token, authenticationtoken, ktor

Друзья, помогите разобраться! В Ktor Client при подключении плагина install (Auth), код ниже, во всех запросах куда должен подкладываться BearerToken сначала приходит в ответ 401 ошибка и только затем запрос отрабатывает как необходимо, в чём может быть причина и как исправить?

```
    install(Auth) {
        bearer {
            loadTokens {
                bearerTokenStorage.last()
            }
            refreshTokens {
                val refreshToken: Token = client.submitForm(
                    startUrl, parameters {
                        append("grant_type", "refresh_token")
                        append("client_id", "admin-cli")
                        append("refresh_token", oldTokens?.refreshToken ?: "Token not found")
                    }
                ) { markAsRefreshTokenRequest() }.body()
                bearerTokenStorage.add(BearerTokens(refreshToken.accessToken, refreshToken.refreshToken))
                bearerTokenStorage.last()
            }
            sendWithoutRequest { request ->
                request.url.host.startsWith(baseUrl)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Это нормально, стучится без токена, затем получает токен после ошибки, затем работает как положено. Судя по всему у вас в `bearerTokenStorage` токены не сохраняются после закрытия сессии.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Да всё верно, токены не сохраняются после закрытия сессии. А возможно как то изменить данное дефолтное поведение, т.е. чтобы он не стучался без токена в ожидании 401, а сразу отправлял запрос с подложенным BearerToken'ом?

Comment: Можно в local storage его хранить, например. Ну или в какую-нибудь БДшку. Если про мобильные говорить, то SharedPrefs / UserDefaults либо Keychain / Keystore тоже подойдут.